# How To HighLight Particular Sentence in Android Using TextView

Tags: android

I am developing eBook Reader.Kindly suggest me how can i hightlight particular sentence of my string in android Like iBook In IOS ,MoonReader in android & many more.

There is any library for it.Kindly suggest me any example or tutorial .

Comment: What, *precisely*, do you mean by "hightlight particular sentence"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code hope this help you

```
textView.setText("This Is Android", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) textView.getText();

    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(FF0000), 6, 15, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    textView.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

It will highlight the text from character 6 to 15

Comment: i dont want to change text color,I want to highlight background.